# What seeds should I get approval for importing food crops to a third world country?

Tags: vegetables, fruits

What seed crops should I look into putting in my pack outside of a change of cloths for my trip? I was blessed with money, but some places where I'll be going are hard to get Mana Pack too, so I figure I might as well bring some high production crops on my trip, and was blessed with a good income, but I'm a big believer in "teach a man to fish he eats for a lifetime".

I'm going to Guatemala on a mission trip this summer.

Comment: You should ask them when you are down there but I think unless your baggage allowance extends to 50 lb sacks of seed that this is not a good idea.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question mainly pertaining to traveling and Customs Law. Probably a better fit on the Travel Stack Exchange

Comment: I second to move this to some type of Travel exchange.

Comment: Groups from our church frequently go on missions trips to Guatemala, and other places, The leaders of the project in the host country help us with questions like that. There are also travel centers in our area, generally the place where we get the shots, who can answer you. In America, you can call the travel department at the Government Offices in your state, or check their website. I think this question is getting migrated, so I hope you'll find your answers wherever it ends up!

Comment: not sacks, just a few for replanting later

Comment: This is not a travel question as it's more about growing food for volume, and calories, not for what can I take to a given country.

Answer (score 0):

In many countries you must get approval before bringing in GMO seeds. Monsanto  broke the law in India by growing GMO crops without approval from the Indian regulatory agency. See [this article](http://goo.gl/rZ0wX5).

Also, in the US, I don't think there are any requirements to label seeds as GMO, at least at the retail level (for those little seed packets).

There are also issues where some countries consider X to be an invasive plant but you shouldn't have that problem with most food plants, but double check to make sure.

Comment: What if they're non-GMO?

Comment: You should always check local laws to prevent getting a big fine or jail time.